# Email sent to 2 addresses with shared same organization domain @123abc.com and one bounced back. Was it successfully delivered to the other address?

Tags: email, email-address

It is my first time asking questions, so my apologies if there is any mistakes. I sent an email to 2 addresses (2 different departments in same organization with shared @123abc.com), one bounced back from mailer-daemon@googlemail.com due to 'address not found'. I later found out it was a generated email address. Could someone please tell me if my email was successfully delivered to the other 'good' address (the other department)?

Comment: If it’s not bounced and that’s a personalized email address then there are quite positive evidences that your email is delivered.

Comment: Thank you @BhargavJoshi for the answer. Greatly appreciated. Both are work email addresses though.